# How to get a post's content?

Tags: posts, tags, slug, content, id

I'd like to known what is the best solution for getting a sepecific post's content. By slug, tag, id or category ? Or template assigned to this post ?

I don't like the way to find this post by its id because the id is not the same on others PC.

Could you give me some advices ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by that "he id is not the same on others PC"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"best" greatly depends on context.

guid is probably (with some debate about it) the best way to uniquely identify a post, but not all import/export plugins leave it alone without changes.

ID is a good identifier if you do not care about import and export.

Slug is problematic because they might be changed by the user.

The best thing to do if you need to know which post you should treat in a special way is to have an admin configuration for it that saves its ID. Then when you need to work with the same code in different environments you can just change the configuration without changing the code.

Comment: You're right ! Thanks, i forgot the configuration of the site is customizable.